# Show that the graph of a continous function defined in a compcat has null measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R} $ be a compact subset and $ f: K \mapsto \mathbb{R^n} $ a continuous function. Show that the graph of $ u $, has null measure. That is, the seet
$$ \{(x,f(x)) \in K \times \mathbb{R}^n : x \in K\})
$$  has null measure.

Comment: (1) what is $K$? (2) not sure what "defined in a compcat is compact" is trying to say (3) is it "constinous" or "continous"? ;)

Comment: $K$ is a compact set. "continuous".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that if $f$ is continuous on a compact than $f$ is uniformily continuous, that means $\forall \epsilon'>0$ $\exists \delta > 0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$ than $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon'$.

Take an $\epsilon>0$, and let $L$ limit $K$, it is, if $k\in K$ than $|k|<L$. From the definition of uniform. cont. with $\epsilon' = \frac{\epsilon}{L^\frac{1}{n}}$, we can divide $K$ into intervals of size $\delta$ where the graph of such intervals is inside of a ball of size $\delta\times\epsilon'^n$, if you sum the volume of all such balls you'll get $V \leq L\times\epsilon'^n$, and it's clear that the grapf of $f$ is inside the union of all such balls. Since we take an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ we proof that the graph of $f$ has zero measure.

Now note that you can use that argument and a smart sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} = 1$ to slice the line $\mathbb{R}^m$ and get an even better result: that if $f: \mathcal{R}^m \to \mathcal{R}^n$ is continuous than its graph has zero measure.